# Datastax Java driver saving timestamp

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using datastax java driver with mapperd

I want to save epoch as timestamp

```
device_id | timestamp                       
--------------------------
  2323 | 1595077868994000 
122112 | 2020-07-25 05:30:00.000000+0000
```

Currently I am using ZonedDate time.. But when I insert record via java code it saves as epoch as shown in Row number 1

```
insert into table (device_id , timestamp ) VALUES ('122112',toTimestamp(toDate(now()))) ;
```

However when I insert with query as above it stored timestamp in more readable format
How can I configure datastax driver to store timestamp in readable format

Here is my entity

```
public class Table {

@PartitionKey(value = 0)
private String deviceId;

private Instant timestamp;
```

Instant was only one which had codec to Timestamp.. I just want to store Timestamp to DB at milli sec accuracy and want it easily readable on UI

THen I am using Object Mapper , Dao and the just calling Save method

```
@Dao
public interface TableDao {

@Insert
boolean save(Table table);
}
```

Comment: Is the `timestamp` column not of `timestamp` type?  If not, this is a good reason why it should be.

Comment: CREATE TABLE table (
    device_id text,
    timestamp timestamp

Comment: Its timestamp column

Comment: Ok.  So what does the relevant Java code look like?

Comment: I have update code. I didnt find any codec for java.util.Date which I can use directly

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp is stored in Cassandra as 8-byte long number.  All conversions to human-readable representations should be done on the client side, for example, converted by [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).  The same happens in `cqlsh` - it receives 8 byte long number, and convert it into textual representation.

**Update, after clarifications**: It looks like that code pushes data as microseconds, not as milliseconds, resulting in the values that are muuuuch into the future, and most probably overloading the Python's date/time representation

Comment: Ok by why do i see 2 different format on row number 1 and 2 ? 2 is which i inserted with query and 1 is with datastax

Comment: do you see it in the `cqlsh` ? What version of Cassandra?

Comment: This number of milliseconds represent `Fri Jan 03 52516 09:49:54`, and I think that Python's implementation is simply overloaded.  I think that you need to remove last three zeros to get something manageable (`Sat Jul 18 2020 13:11:08` - if we take without `000`).  Sometimes it's confusing that timestamp of the value in `USING TIMESTAMP` is in microseconds, while actual timestamp value is milliseconds

Comment: Wow.. Got it.. But now the real question. How do i remove last 3 0's in Instant data type ? or change something in cqlsh so that it shows readeable text timestamp

Comment: Instant correctly represent the data - I think that your incoming data are in microseconds... You need to check how you assign data to that `Instant` field